# How to change color of a feature clicked on azure maps?

Tags: java, android, azure-maps

So i have a data source beeing loaded in a symbolLayer in Azure Maps, all its working fine. But i cant find a way to show to my user what feature is beeing clicked on the map.
Here is my code.
I cant get the information about the feature is beeing clicked, but i cant find the way to change the style of the feature.
Anything that can show the user that he clicked that feature its ok for me. Even a dot on top of the feature.
If you guys know what is doing my popup to appear not on top of my feature but overlapping him i would aprecciate too.

```
Popup popup = new Popup();
            map.popups.add(popup);
            //Add a click event to the layer.
            map.events.add((OnFeatureClick)(feature) -> {
                //Get the first feature and it's properties.
                Feature f = feature.get(0);
                JsonObject props = f.properties();
                //Retrieve the custom layout for the popup.
                View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_text, null);
                //Display the name and entity type information of the feature into the text view of the popup layout.
                TextView tv = customView.findViewById(R.id.message);
                tv.setText(f.getStringProperty("Name") + "\n" +
                        f.getStringProperty("Pvm"));
                


                //Get the position of the clicked feature.
                Position pos = MapMath.getPosition((Point)f.geometry());



                //Set the options on the popup.
                popup.setOptions(
                        //Set the popups position.
                        position(pos),

                        //Set the anchor point of the popup content.
                        anchor(AnchorType.BOTTOM),

                        //Set the content of the popup.
                        content(customView),

                        //add a button to close popup
                        closeButton(false)
                );

                //Open the popup.
                popup.open();

                map.events.add((OnClick) (lat, lon) -> {
                    //Map clicked.
                    popup.close(customView);
                    popup.setOptions(iconImage("ic_square_w"));
                    //Return true indicating if event should be consumed and not passed further to other listeners registered afterwards, false otherwise.
                    return true;
                });







                //Return a boolean indicating if event should be consumed or continue to bubble up.
                return true;
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to add a visual highlight that shape has been selected, is to use a second datasource, and add a feature to it and render it with a layer differently.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did, thanks for ur answer. It solved my question.